# How to display date/time according to device settings

Tags: android, datetime, android-dateutils

I simply want to display a date/time according to *device locale* **and** *settings* like *12h/24h* mode.

Having take a look at several posts here on SO, I finally tried to use this:

```
long millis = this.startDate.getTime();
if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)) { // Why do I have to check that ?!?
    strDate = DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, millis, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_24HOUR);
} else {
    strDate = DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, millis, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
}
```

Unfortunately, `DateUtils.FORMAT_24HOUR` is now deprecated so, I wonder how to display a date taking care of device local and settings?

So SimpleDateFormat is not an expected answer as I don't want to specify the format myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try android.text.format.DateFormat, notably getDateFormatOrder() to get the user's preferred date format.